# printng outputs to another folder

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to use the following code(Ref:-Perreal) to run multiple files. Instead of printing the outputs one by one, I want to save the outputs of each file to another folder with the filenames of input.

Any help would be appreciated!!

```
for i in folder1/*.txt;
do
awk '
BEGIN {
 path=sprintf("%s", "/home/chima/Desktop/folder2/")
}
!s[1":"$4":"$5]++{sU[$4]++;tot++}
!s[2":"$4":"$5]++{sU[$5]++;tot++} 
END {
for (x in sU)
print x, sU[x], sU[$1] > path FILENAME;
print "Total No -",tot > path FILENAME;
}'  $i;
done
```

Error:-

```
awk: cmd. line:9: (FILENAME=folder1/file1.txt FNR=955) fatal: can't redirect to `/home/chima/Desktop/folder2/folder1/file1.txt' (No such file or directory)
```

Actually folder1 and folder2 are on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the path in the `BEGIN` section and use it as a regular awk variable after print statements. **FILENAME** is an `awk` built-in variable that stores the name of the file being processed.

```
for i in files/*.txt;
do
awk '
BEGIN {
    path=sprintf("%s", "/path/to/anotherfolder/")
}
!s[1":"$4":"$5]++{sU[$4]++;tot++} 
!s[2":"$4":"$5]++{sU[$5]++;tot++} 
END { 
    sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME)
    for (x in sU) 
        print x, sU[x], sU[$1] > path FILENAME;
        print "Total No -",tot > path FILENAME;
}'  $i;
 done
```

Comment: I tried it. I get an error like this awk: cmd. line:9: (FILENAME=folder1/file1.txt FNR=955) fatal: can't redirect to `/home/chima/Desktop/folder2folder1/file1.txt' (No such file or directory)

Comment: Add a `/` in your path variable. `folder2folder1` in your error message looks like it is missing a forward slash.

Comment: I checked it. forward slash hasn't missed.

Comment: can you update the question with what you have now? It would be easy to see the problem that way.

Comment: @user2447904 Try the updated solution. I added `sub` function to remove the preceding folder1 name from the FILENAME variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I get only one output(instead of all files) in folder2. Output file name is 1 instead of its parent name.

Comment: @user2447904 Sorry my bad. I edited the sub function. Try this and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

change your print statement to :

```
print "Total No -",tot >"/home/user/anotherfolder/"FILENAME;
```